# Mesibo App: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x, mesibo

I have run the sample Python script provide by you on your website. I get an
sql error:

```
 **E(0108-124524-289)(9417): sql error in insert: insert into messages (mid, gid, channel, type, ts, status, expiry, flag, sender, message, thumbnail, filepath, rts, uflags) VALUES ("961428429235933", 0, 0, 0, 1596216731289, 18, 0, 0, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0, 0) (constraint failed)**
**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Segmentation fault (core dumped) occurs on running the listener Python script

Answer (score 1):

Clear your database and see if the issue persists. Ensure you are using the latest version of [mesibo python package](https://github.com/mesibo/python). Try running this [script](https://pastebin.pl/view/c8a06d59)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are prematurely exiting from the script and hence the crash. Note that mesibo.start() is an async call and it returns immediately. If you are not doing anything after mesibo.start(), use some kind of wait call or use mesibo.wait()